# Possible No of Instance there when same singleton class is packaged in two war file?

Tags: java, singleton

How many number of Instance  can be there when same singleton class is packaged in two war file(and both war files are packaged in 
one ear file)

Cas1

MyUnderstanding
As per my understanding for singleton class there will be a single instance per JVM. So as per this answer for above should be one instance
as there will be one instance of jvm for the ear file.

Case2

But on differnt sites(one at http://www.coderanch.com/t/520891/java/java/Singleton-Diff-WAR-files-same) , folks have also mentioned singleton produces
 the  single instance for a class loader. they said for two war files there will be two class loader . So ther will be two instance of singleton.

What is the right answer?

If second case is right can we say below statements

1)For singleton class there will be a single instance per classloader(here i mean classloader hirerchy in a jvm instance that includes bootstrap loader, 
application class loader) not for jvm.

2)For two war files packaged in same ear file there will be two  classloader hirerchies under same jvm instance

posted at http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2253940&tstart=0 but not concrete answer

Comment: It could very well depend on what makes it a singleton - how is its "singletoncy" implemented

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) If your class is in each WAR, then there will be an instance per webapp (classloader herarchy).

2) Yes.